# How to remove quotes from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I came across this problem in my project in which I have lists which append from a life to a list. Please see below.

```
Log_info = [ "['carl@gmail.com', 'carl120', 'Carl']", "['brandi.love@gmail.com', 'brandih0t', 'Brandi']" ]
```

Above is the list that have been pull from a file (TXT)

Below is what I want it to look like: I want to remove `""` so they are sub list in a list, but I can't seem to find how.

```
Log_info = [ ['carl@gmail.com', 'carl120', 'Carl'], ['brandi.love@gmail.com', 'brandih0t', 'Brandi'] ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [literal_eval(i) for i in Log_info]
[['carl@gmail.com', 'carl120', 'Carl'],
 ['brandi.love@gmail.com', 'brandih0t', 'Brandi']]
```

Comment: Thanks you!!! Thank you!!! Now I need more to learn about python, Thank you!!!:D